# How to get called back from an sync method call without waiting for it?

Tags: asynchronous, ejb, wildfly, java-ee-8

I want to write a method in an EJB class which is declared with async because of long running,
i don't want to wait for the result but i want get informed on Done or Error.

Something like this (Pseudo-Code only, because don't know how to do it right):

**EJB / Locale async bean:**

```
@LocaleBean
@Stateless
public AsyncEJBTest {
    @Asynchronous
    public Future<String> longRunningFunction(String name) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000); // Simulate long running
        } catch(Exception e) {
            //
        }
        return new AsyncResult<String>(String.format("The result for %s has been calculated !", name));
    }
}
```

**CDI / Client - example:**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @EJB
  private AsyncEJBTest test;

  public void StartTestClick() {
    Future<String> result = test.longRunningFunction("John doe");
    while(!result.isDone()) {
        System.out.println("Calculating..."); // Client is blocked here 
        Thread.sleep(300);
    }   
    // Continue with result, after long waiting ...
  }
}
```

But as i have seen only examples in which i need to wait on the client/cdi side for the result,
so my client is blocked as i don't use the asynchronous tag.

So is there another way to "inform" the cdi-client out from an enterprise bean when the "calculation" or whatever has been finished ?

The thing i want to do is to create new databases on demand by cloning them, automatically configure the wildfly server with the new data sources by using cli/command line interface programmatically and the inform the user that the new databases are now available.
This takes a lot of time, so i will get a timeout when i wait on the client side for the result - and async seems only working on EJB side without blocking when i dont need a result ...

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to write the `Future<String>` handle to an ApplicationScoped bean (probably a list of them). Then have a "check" button in your page and when you press the button, the client application checks each `Future<String>` handle listed in the application bean. If the job is now done (or cancelled) it removes the handle from the list and displays a message.

If this is too passive, consider putting something on the page template or implementing a check on each page navigation. If you're wanting an instantaneous popup notification, investigate JSF 2.3 Push capability and f:websocket. Or there's always a boring old email generated at the end of the async job. You need to think through how you want to be notified, and also what happens if the async job fails and/or you're no longer using the application when the job finishes, or if the application gets restarted.

#### Client view

```java
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class AsyncClientController implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Inject
    private FacesContext facesContext;
    @Inject
    private AsyncJobController jobController;
    @Inject
    private AsyncEJBStatelessBean asyncBean;

    public void startAsync() {
        String name = "Job " + 
            LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
        Future<String> handle = asyncBean.longRunningJob(name);
        jobController.add(handle);
        facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Submitted", null));
    }

    public void checkResults() {
        String res = jobController.getNewResults();
        if (res == null || res.isBlank()) {
            facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, 
                    "No new results", "Jobs logged: " + Integer.toString(jobController.size())));
        } else {
            facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "New results", res));
        }
    }

}
```

#### Application Bean

```java
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class AsyncJobController implements java.io.Serializable {

    private final List<Future<String>> handlesList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(Future<String> handle) {
        handlesList.add(handle);
    }

    public String getNewResults() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        List<Future<String>> finishedList = new ArrayList<>();

        handlesList.stream()
                .filter(handle -> (handle.isDone()))
                .forEachOrdered(handle -> {
                    finishedList.add(handle);
                });

        for (Future<String> handle : finishedList) {
            try {
                builder.append(builder.length() == 0 ? "" : "'\n'")
                        .append(handle.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AsyncJobController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            handlesList.remove(handle);
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }

    public int size() {
        return handlesList.size();
    }
}
```

#### Async Stateless EJB

```java
@Stateless
@Asynchronous
public class AsyncEJBStatelessBean {
    
    @Inject
    private Logger log;
    
    public Future<String> longRunningJob(String name) {
        
        long sleepTime = (long) (Math.random()*60 + 0.5); // 1 .. 60
        log.log(Level.INFO, "Starting job ''{0}'' with duration {1}", 
                new Object[]{name, Long.toString(sleepTime)});
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime * 1000);     // milliseconds
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // do nothing
        }
        String res = "Job '" + name + "' finished after " + Long.toString(sleepTime) + " seconds";
        log.log(Level.INFO, "{0}", res);
        return new AsyncResult<>(res);
    }
    
}
```